# Postgres & FULL TEXT SEARCH: What is the correct SQL query to search for a phrase with multiple negate phrases

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table with a `description` column.

In this table, I have added an extra column called `tsv` that is populated with the tsvector of the description.

I'm trying to query the `tsv` column for a certain phrase but add negate phrases to reduce the number of false positives returned, but I'm not sure what the correct way is to do it as I get a different number of result returned for each way I am trying.

For example, take **stream**, as in a little river.

I get

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', '
        stream
    ')

RETURNS: 26
```

But in some of the descriptions as I have checked all 26 manually, they only talk about:

> ...light streaming in from both the window... (There is 1 with this in)

or

> ...stream of natural light...
>   (There are 2 with this in)

Which is nothing to do with a little stream of running water.

That's a total of 3, so I am expecting 23 to be returned instead.

Here's what I have tried so far, none of which return 23:

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', '
        stream
        & ! light<->streaming
        | ! stream<2>natural<->light
    ')

>RETURNS: 261
```

or

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', '
        stream
        & ! light<->streaming
        & ! stream<2>natural<->light
    ')

>RETURNS: 3
```

or

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', '
        stream
        & ! ( 
            light<->streaming
            | stream<2>natural<->light
        )
    ')

>RETURNS: 8
```

or

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', '
        stream
        & ( 
            ! light<->streaming
            | ! stream<2>natural<->light
        )
    ')

>RETURNS: 26
```

What am I doing wrong?
Or is there a completely different way I need to be doing this?

Thanks in advance

**ADDITION**

Just so I know for sure and for my sanity, I rang this code for each term I'm trying to negate

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english',
        'light<->streaming'
     )

>RETURNS: 1
```

```
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english',
        'stream<2>natural<->light'
     )

>RETURNS: 2
```

Both returned the records I want removing from the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOLLOW UP**

I couldn't solve this doing it the way I was trying to do it
e.g. all within one clause.

So to get around the issue, I create separate where clauses for each negate term.

So instead of

```
...  
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english',
                        'stream
                         & !(light <-> stream)
                         & !(stream <2> natural <-> light)'
                     );
```

I did this instead

```
...
WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english','stream')
AND NOT WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english','light <-> stream')
AND NOT WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english','stream <2> natural <-> light')
```

Doing it this way produced the results I was expecting.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The negation operator `!` binds stronger than `<->`, so you'll have to use parentheses correctly:

```
... WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery(
                    'english',
                    'stream
                     & !(light <-> stream)
                     & !(stream <2> natural <-> light)'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I've just used your format and it returns 8, not the 23 I was expecting.

Comment: Well, show an example of a row that should be returned, but is not.

Comment: Just looked at one that should have been returned and checked the tsv values:
'light':101,340
'stream':26,209,813
there are no natural vector values

Comment: It works here. Are you using an index? If yes, does `REINDEX` on that index help?